# Cannot call CSS class from datatable server side in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, json, ajax, datatable

I need your help for my case. I have a problem with using datatable-serverside, the class "open_modal" cannot called by javascript.

If I use general datatable and display the data with php, the open_modal class works fine.

The result of the data is exactly same with this example, in this example we can call  the open_modal class. Not work if I use datatable-serverside.
[My Example Open Modal with JS](http://www.codeply.com/go/QUYzPuY752)

Can you help me?
Thank you.

Datatable code:

```
$('#datatable-serverside').DataTable({
    "iDisplayLength": 5,
    "aLengthMenu": [[5, 25, 50, 100, -1], [5, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
    "bProcessing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        url: "supplier/response.php", // json datasource
        type: "post", // type of method  ,GET/POST/DELETE
        "dataSrc": function (jsonData) {
            for (var i = 0, len = jsonData.data.length; i < len; i++) {
                jsonData.data[i][2] = jsonData.data[i][2] + '<br>' + jsonData.data[i][3];
                jsonData.data[i][3] = jsonData.data[i][4];
                jsonData.data[i][4] = '<button type="button" class="open_modal btn btn-success" id_supplier="' + jsonData.data[i][5] + '" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>';
            }

            return jsonData.data;
        },
        error: function () {
            $("#supplier_grid").append('<tbody><tr><th colspan="5">Cannot display the data.</th></tr></tbody>');
        }
    }
});
```

Javascript code:

```
var $lba = document.getElementsByClassName('open_modal');

function myPopup() {
    var m = $(this).attr("id_supplier");
    $.ajax({
        url: "supplier/modal_edit.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {id: m, },
        success: function (ajaxData) {
            $("#ModalEdit").html(ajaxData);
            $("#ModalEdit").modal('show', {backdrop: 'true'});
        }
    });
}
for (var i = 0; i < $lba.length; i++)
    $lba[i].onclick = myPopup;
```

**Yay! Solved by myself! ^_^**
I changed my function with onclick, thank you.

```
jsonData.data[i][4] = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="editForm(\'ModalEdit\', \''+ jsonData.data[i][5] +'\')" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>';
```

.

```
function editForm(id, value) {
var e = document.getElementById(id);
if (e.style.display == 'none') {
    var m = value;
    $.ajax({
        url: "modul/mod_supplier/modal_edit.php",
        type: "GET",
        data: {id: m, },
        success: function (ajaxData) {
            $("#ModalEdit").html(ajaxData);
            $("#ModalEdit").modal('show', {backdrop: 'true'});
        }
    });
}}
```

Comment: you can't call a CSS class

Comment: can you explain that loop at the end?

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, the class is open_modal. <button type="button" class="open_modal btn btn-success" ... The function of this class is to call edit form with modal bootstrap.

Comment: @Roysh : the loop of what? in the javascript code? This is just to call myPopup function. This function is work fine, if use general datatable (without any configuration). the open_modal class can called by javascript. But with datatable serverside not working. I checked the page source, with general datatable and datatable serverside, it's same, like this: <button type="button" class="open_modal btn btn-success" id_supplier="1" title="Edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit</button>

Comment: make a jsfiddle or your issue.

Comment: @MarouenMhiri here is my example to call open_modal class: works fine. http://www.codeply.com/go/QUYzPuY752

Comment: if you're relying entirely on that dev space, alerts are forbidden. look at the console. also add that var into console.log and see what you get back. you're code is fine. also i think @OrieWancu has a fix for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code regarding list of Table data. There are different columns like "Count","Code","Name","Status","Oppo" in data table.

```
           "ajax": {
             "url": 'URL',
             "type": 'POST',
             "dataSrc": function (Jsondata) {
                var dataArray = [];
                for (key in Jsondata.data) {
                   dataArray.push({
                     "Count": Jsondata.data[key].ListCount,
                     "Code": Jsondata.data[key].Code,
                     "Name": '<a href="javascript:;" class="open_modal ' + 
                              Jsondata.data[key].Status + '" onclick=fnView("' 
                              + Jsondata.data[key].ID + '","' + 
                             Jsondata.data[key].ID1 + '")>EDIT</a>',
                    "Status": Jsondata.data[key].Status,                                
                    "Oppo": Jsondata.data[key].Opp
                    });
                }
                return dataArray;
             }
```